# Why does Graphpad Prism return 4 pairwise contrasts and not 6 from DunnettT3 of 4 groups?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

These data are not mine but are from Figure 7C of [Induction of osteogenesis by bone-targeted Notch activation](https://elifesciences.org/articles/60183). Note that the design is 2 x 2 factorial but analyzed as single factor (4 x 1).

```
Ctrl    Dll4(E12)   PTH PTH+Dll4(E12)
2.518   2.779   2.353   3.301
2.907   2.614   3.099   5.301
2.797   2.538   2.933   3.168
2.701   2.308   2.812   5.414
2.595   2.409   2.988   6.873
```

The archived data includes the GraphPad Prism results in the archived Excel file. These results include this output:

[image]

Why are there only 4 contrasts and not six? Even the output summary states that there are 4 groups but only 4 comparisons. How are the subset of 4 chosen? I don't know if this is the default GraphPad Prism behavior, or if there is a menu allowing the user to choose a subset of contrasts, or if this is a bug.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a choice in GraphPad Prism that lets you choose only selected pairs of means to compare.
[image: Prism dialog screenshot]

This can make sense in some rare situations. Of course, that choice should be made on scientific grounds before seeing the data (and not made after seeing the results to try to nudge a p-value lower -- p-hacking).

That answers your question of whether Prism allows followup tests after ANOVA of only selected comparisons. The underlying question is WHY the investigators chose that route. You'd need to ask them, as it doesn't seem to be answered in the paper.

Comment: Thanks Harvey Motulsky! And I agree with your comment on WHY.